# Convert object with arrays to array of objects using Ramda or Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

Example input:

```js
const obj = {
  paths: ['path1', 'path2'],
  thumbnails: ['thumb1', 'thumb2'],
  sizes: [ // may not always be presented
    [100, 200],
    [120, 220],
  ],
};
```

Expected output:

```js
const result = [
  {
    path: 'path1',
    thumbnail: 'thumb1',
    size: [100, 200],
  },
  {
    path: 'path2',
    thumbnail: 'thumb2',
    size: [120, 220],
  },
];
```

Bonus points for:

```js
const result1 = [
  {
    path: 'path1',
    thumbnail: 'thumb1',
    width: 100,
    height: 200,
  },
  {
    path: 'path2',
    thumbnail: 'thumb2',
    width: 120,
    height: 220,
  },
];

// without sizes

const result2 = [
  {
    path: 'path1',
    thumbnail: 'thumb1',
  },
  {
    path: 'path2',
    thumbnail: 'thumb2',
  },
];
```

How would I achieve this with Ramda or Lodash?

Answer (score 2):

## Updated answer

Here we extract the fields we care about into arrays, turn that into a multidimensional array (number of records by  number of elements in an array), transpose that array, and then zip it back together as an object.

We use the same list of field names for the extraction and for reconstituting an object.  It looks like this:

```js
const inflate = (names) => (obj) =>  
  map (zipObj (names)) (transpose (props (names) (obj)))

const obj = {paths: ['path1', 'path2'], thumbnails: ['thumb1', 'thumb2'], sizes: [[100, 200], [120, 220]]}

console .log (inflate (['paths', 'thumbnails', 'sizes']) (obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {map, zipObj, transpose, props, paths} = R </script>
```

For your extended version, just run a subsequent `map` over the results:

```js
const inflate = (names) => (obj) =>  
  map (zipObj (names)) (transpose (props (names) (obj)))
    .map (({sizes: [width, height], ...rest}) => ({...rest, width, height}))
```

### A specification-based approach

Ori Drori's answer challenged me to find a specification-based version that lets us declare that `paths` becomes `path` and the first element of `sizes` becomes `width`.  Here is one rather nasty version of that idea.  I'm out of time to clean it up, but you can see at least the skeleton of an interesting idea in this:

```js
const regroup = (spec, names = uniq (values (spec) .map (x => x.split ('.') [0]))) => (obj) => 
  map (applySpec (map (pipe (split ('.'), path)) (spec))) (map (zipObj (names)) (transpose (props (names) (obj))))


const obj = {paths: ['path1', 'path2'], thumbnails: ['thumb1', 'thumb2'], sizes: [[100, 200], [120, 220]]}
const spec = {path: 'paths', thumbnail: 'thumbnails', width: 'sizes.0', height: 'sizes.1'}

console .log (regroup (spec) (obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {uniq, values, map, applySpec, pipe, split, path, zipObj, transpose, props} = R </script>
```

## Original answer

(I originally misread and thought you wanted something like the Cartesian product of the elements, not the matched indices one.  I'm leaving it here as it does answer what to my mind is a more interesting question.)

### TLDR

Below we discuss several  implementations.  A configurable one written in Ramda looks like this:

```js
const inflate = pipe (map (unwind), pipeWith (chain))
// ...
inflate (['paths', 'thumbnails', 'sizes', 'sizes']) (obj)
```

A powerful, but less flexible vanilla one looks like this:

```js
const inflate = (obj, _, __, field = Object .entries (obj) .find (([k, v]) => Array .isArray (v))) => 
  field ? field [1] .flatMap ((v) => inflate ({...obj, [field [0]]: v})) : obj
// ...
inflate (obj)
```

### Ramda implementation

Ramda has a function dedicated to this: [`unwind`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unwind).  It takes a property name and returns an array of values, one for each element of the array at that name.  We can then simply pipe these together with `chain`, like this:

```js
const inflate = pipeWith (chain) ([
  unwind ('paths'),
  unwind ('thumbnails'),
  unwind ('sizes'),
  unwind ('sizes')
])

const obj = {paths: ['path1', 'path2'], thumbnails: ['thumb1', 'thumb2'], sizes: [[100, 200], [120, 220]]}

console .log (inflate (obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipeWith, chain, unwind} = R                             </script>
```

If `pipeWith` is unfamiliar, this is equivalent to

```js
const inflate = pipe (
  unwind ('paths'),
  chain (unwind ('thumbnails')),
  chain (unwind ('sizes')),
  chain (unwind ('sizes'))
)
```

where the `chain` calls are acting here similar to `Array.prototype.flatMap`.

### More abstract Ramda implementation

But this calls out for a further abstraction.  We can make that more declarative by extracting the list of paths we want to expand, so that we can simply call `inflate (['paths', 'thumbnails', 'sizes', 'sizes']) (obj)`.  This is an implementation:

```js
const inflate = pipe (map (unwind), pipeWith (chain))

const obj = {paths: ['path1', 'path2'], thumbnails: ['thumb1', 'thumb2'], sizes: [[100, 200], [120, 220]]}

console .log (inflate (['paths', 'thumbnails', 'sizes', 'sizes']) (obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, map, pipeWith, chain, unwind} = R                  </script>
```

### Powerful, but less flexible vanilla implementation

But perhaps we don't want to specify the fields.  If we just want to supply the object and expand all arrays, including nested ones, then we probably want to write a recursive version.  At this point, Ramda would probably be a distraction.  We can write a simple vanilla JS implementation like this:

```js
const inflate = (obj, _, __, field = Object .entries (obj) .find (([k, v]) => Array .isArray (v))) => 
  field ? field [1] .flatMap ((v) => inflate ({...obj, [field [0]]: v})) : obj


const obj = {paths: ['path1', 'path2'], thumbnails: ['thumb1', 'thumb2'], sizes: [[100, 200], [120, 220]]}

console .log (inflate (obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This is powerful.  It works with any array properties, even if they're multidimensional.  But it is inflexible.  You cannot choose *not* to expand certain array properties.  Whether this is good or bad will depend upon your circumstances.

We *could* use Ramda in the same manner.  Here's a partial conversion to using Ramda functions:

```js
const inflate = (obj) => call (
  (field = pipe (toPairs, find (pipe (last, is(Array)))) (obj), [k, v] = field || []) =>
    field ? chain ((v) => inflate (assoc (k, v, obj))) (field [1]) : obj 
)
```

And we could continue to pull things out until we were totally point-free, but I think we'd slowly be *losing* readability here, unlike with the earlier Ramda versions, where we ended up with fairly elegant, readable implementations.

### Names

None of these versions (in the original or updated answers) does name changes.  We don't try to convert "sizes" to "size" or "paths" to "path".  If you have control over the input format, I would suggest that you simply switch it there.  If not, I would probably do that as a final step.  You can do that using Ramda's [`applySpec`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec) or perhaps using something like [`renameKeys`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#rename-keys-of-an-object) from Ramda's [Cookbook](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook).  While it might be possible to fold this key renaming into the functions above, I would expect it to be less robust than simply doing a second pass.

Comment: Spec-based approach is neat. Also running `Ramda implementation`, `More abstract Ramda implementation` and `Powerful, but less flexible vanilla implementation` didn't produce an intended result. `sizes` property is of type `number` and property names are off

Comment: Right, as I said, I originally misread the question, but kept them here as the answer to a somewhat related question.  The only ones close to your actual requirements are the first two.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to pass a mapping of old keys to new keys, use `R.props` to get the value using the old keys, transpose, and then zip back to an object using the new keys (the values of the `mappings` object):

```js
const {pipe, props, keys, transpose, map, zipObj, values} = R

const fn = mapping => pipe(
  props(keys(mapping)), // get an array props by keys order
  transpose, // transpose them
  map(zipObj(values(mapping))) // map back to an object with the same order
)

const obj = {paths: ['path1', 'path2'], thumbnails: ['thumb1', 'thumb2'], sizes: [[100, 200], [120, 220]]}

console.log(fn({ paths: 'path', thumbnails: 'thumbnail', sizes: 'size' })(obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice, I considered doing such a mapping, but chose to go in another direction.  An interesting extension would be using a specification such as `{path: 'paths', thumbnail: 'thumbnails', width: 'sizes.0', height: 'sizes.1'}`,

Comment: Updated my answer to include a version with that sort of specification.

Comment: I like your solution, very clean

Answer (score 0):

You specifically want to do this using ramada only ?

Coz this can be achieved with vanilla as follows.

for expected output -

```
obj.paths.map((e, i) => ({ path: obj.paths[i], thumbnail: obj.thumbnails[i], size: obj.sizes[i] }))
```

for bonus output -

```
obj.paths.map((e, i) => ({ path: obj.paths[i], thumbnail: obj.thumbnails[i], width: obj.sizes[i][0], height: obj.sizes[i][1] }))
```

size array can be empty ie. [] -

```
obj.paths.map((e, i) => ({ path: obj.paths[i], thumbnail: obj.thumbnails[i], width: obj.sizes[i] !== undefined ? obj.sizes[i][0] : '', height: obj.sizes[i] !== undefined ? obj.sizes[i][1] : ''}))
```

Comment: thanks! just updated the question, `sizes` property may not be always presented as a whole

Comment: thanks, though vanilla js solution is mostly trivial I'm looking for a ramda way of doing this specifically for the sake of our code base style

Answer (score 0):

With vanilla Javascript, we can handle with indices easily, but Ramda.js does not have them, so you can use `R.forEachObjIndexed` to handle your case.

```
const obj = {
  paths: ['path1', 'path2'],
  thumbnails: ['thumb1', 'thumb2'],
  sizes: [ // may not always be presented
    [100, 200],
    [120, 220],
  ],
};

const result = []
R.forEachObjIndexed((value, index) => {
  const currentData = {
    path: value,
  }
  if(obj.thumbnails && obj.thumbnails[index]) {
    currentData.thumbnail = obj.thumbnails[index]
  }
  if(obj.sizes && obj.sizes[index]) {
    const [width, height] = obj.sizes[index]
    currentData.width = width
    currentData.height = height
  }
  result.push(currentData)
}, obj.paths)

console.log(result)
```

You can try out with the playground [here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.28.0#?const%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20paths%3A%20%5B%27path1%27%2C%20%27path2%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20thumbnails%3A%20%5B%27thumb1%27%2C%20%27thumb2%27%5D%2C%0A%20%20sizes%3A%20%5B%20%2F%2F%20may%20not%20always%20be%20presented%0A%20%20%20%20%5B100%2C%20200%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5B120%2C%20220%5D%2C%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0AR.forEachObjIndexed%28%28value%2C%20index%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20currentData%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20path%3A%20value%2C%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20if%28obj.thumbnails%20%26%26%20obj.thumbnails%5Bindex%5D%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20currentData.thumbnail%20%3D%20obj.thumbnails%5Bindex%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20if%28obj.sizes%20%26%26%20obj.sizes%5Bindex%5D%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20%5Bwidth%2C%20height%5D%20%3D%20obj.sizes%5Bindex%5D%0A%20%20%20%20currentData.width%20%3D%20width%0A%20%20%20%20currentData.height%20%3D%20height%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20result.push%28currentData%29%0A%7D%2C%20obj.paths%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%28result%29)